# daemontools and ulimit

Tags: freebsd, ulimit

I have a daemontools service whose `/service/myservice/run` contains:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec setuidgid someuser somecommand
```

Now, if I run this as a script directly from a root shell, `somecommand` will get a correct ulimit (unlimited).

However, when I start the service using

```
svc -u /service/myservice
```

then `somecommand` does get a ulimit effectively slightly above 11000.

How can I have somecommand get the correct ulimit even when started via svc (not from a shell)?

This is on FreeBSD 9 release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the `ulimit` in the `daemontools` script, above the exec. `svc` does not propagate the rlimits to the scripts it runs:

```
#!/bin/sh
ulimit -n 102400 #Increase file descriptor limit to 102400
exec setuidgid someuser somecommand
```

Answer (score 4):

Actually, this is what **softlimit** is for.

You should try:

```
exec setuidgid someuser softlimit -o 102400 somecommand
```

See: http://cr.yp.to/daemontools/softlimit.html

Note that -o controls open file descriptors for softlimit, unlike -n for ulimit.